# PHP style="background-image(..." breaking my javascript in fun new ways

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-theming, gradient

Oohhhhh boy. So I have this really hacky PHP here, but I'm teaching myself as I go in a wordpress theme dev project.

Trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/awgreenblatt/gradientmaps) rad gradientMaps API and discovered a bizarre bug. When I apply my js function to my PHP-constructed element the whole thing breaks unless I remove the > from the end of my html element and allow it to swallow the opening tag of the next element (in this case, "

I've been hacking away at it for hours and yes, I tried reconstructing my PHP in new ways, but this is the only way it seems to render for me:

```
            <?php 
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");

        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
        echo '<div class="recent-posts flexbox">';
         foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
             echo "<div class=\"flex-section-3 rpost-thumb\" style=\"background-image: url(";
             the_post_thumbnail_url();
             // reference point here
             echo ")\">"; 
             ?>
        <h4 class="rpost-category">
         <?php es_entry_category(); ?>
        </h4>
```

Like I said, hacky.

When I add the my class to run the gradientMap javascript over the element, this is what shows up in the console:

```
    <div class="flex-section-3 random-grad rpost-thumb" style="background-image: url("http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20161222_203726-1200x675.jpg"); filter: url("#filter-1485467730713");" <h4 data-gradientmap-filter="filter-1485467730713">
     Category <!-- this is the text result of es_entry_category() -->        
         <div class="rpost-meta">
           <div class="rpost-meta-wrapper">
           ...
```

As far as I can tell, the issue is that the js is adding more style attributes and my \" just after my commented reference point is closing out the style="" attribute before all the gradientmap stuff is added in there. But I can't really lose the style="background..." business without losing the dynamic background url capability (php function the_post_thumbnail_url). I have googled my face off and I can't figure this out.

So  A) is there some obvious solution I'm completely missing?
and B) is there some other PHP syntax I can use to clean up this ridiculous web of echos and muted quotes and hopefully fix my problem that way?

Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6826qqr/) for more context. I really appreciate any help I can get on this one!

Comment: It looks like the `<div class="recent-posts flexbox">` is missing a closing `</div>` after the loop. Not sure if that will help the issue.

Comment: Checked and double-checked, that's definitely not it. Having two divs in the PHP code makes the fiddle read as if the div opening and closing tags aren't lining up, but they do. Thanks for your hep though!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");

        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
        echo '<div class="recent-posts flexbox">';
         foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
             echo '<div class="flex-section-3 rpost-thumb" style="background-image: url("';
             echo the_post_thumbnail_url();
             // reference point here
             echo '")>'; 
             ?>
        <h4 class="rpost-category">
         <?php es_entry_category(); ?>
        </h4>
```

This may solve the problem, use ' ', also not calling echo in the_post_thumbnail_url(); may make the value to not be printed in the html string

Comment: This feels like Michigan the frog - that WAS breaking the PHP now it's not (admittedly this may have been due to a syntax error on my part).

Nonetheless the problem is still presenting. The js breaks somehow unless I take out the final > from the div.

Comment: Sorry, that may be my bad I had in my code echo '")'>"; and not echo '")>';, try now and see

Comment: Actually I implemented it myself - both your examples are missing the " to close the style="background-image:url()" attribute. :) To be sure though, I did try all three versions.

This is what worked:
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<div class="flex-section-3 random-grad rpost-thumb" style="background-image: url(';
        the_post_thumbnail_url();
        echo ')"'; 
     ?>